# Accessing basic Facebook session

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to develop a basic app that uses the Facebook Graph object. I am having a really hard time understanding how to work with basic facebook sessions. Currently, I am able to login to facebook by having the app prompt the user for permission. Once permission is given, the app redirects to the `$redirect_url` below. Although, once I get to the actual redirected `app.php` script, I am having a hard time accessing the graph object for extended time without getting an error such as:

```
Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'This authorization code has been used.
```

Currently the `signin.php` code redirects successfully and before the redirect takes place, the script is capable of accessing graph object successfully

```
$app_id = '12334567890';
$app_secret = 'zzzwewe123456789ad8';
$redirect_url = 'http://localhost/www/concept/app.php';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if(isset($sess)){
    $access_token = $sess->getToken();
    $session = new FacebookSession($access_token);
    $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
    $name = $graph->getName();
    echo $name;
}else{
    echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl().'"> Login with facebook</a>';
}
```

Once the redirect takes place (to `app.php`), I am unable to access the graph object without getting the error: `Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'This authorization code has been used.`

app.php

```
    $app_id = '12334567890';
    $app_secret = 'zzzwewe123456789ad8';
$redirect_url = 'http://localhost/www/concept/app.php';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url, $app_id, $app_secret);
 $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
```

All I am trying to do at this point, is just output the name of the user on the redirect page, using the graph object and I need to be able to refresh the page without getting the above mentioned error.

I truly appreciate any advice

Comment: I don't understand from your two code snippets how you are able to query any data, and at what point exactly your program loses the ability to make graph API requests. It looks like you should change your `app.php` to store the access token you received from the redirect in your web server's session manager. see [PHP's session docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Then, you'll want to change `signing.php` script to instantiate a `FacebookSession` from the token stored in the user's browser session (you stored it there after the redirect, in `app.php`).

Comment: Typically the flow is as follows: 1) check if user's browser session contains an access token. 1.a) if so, make graph API requests. 1.b) if not, initiate login redirect flow. 2) after getting redirected back from Fb's login dialog, capture the access token and store it in the user's browser session. 3) now go back to step 1) and 1.a.